# Can this Flash tool be done with JavaScript (jQuery)/HTML5/CSS3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a tool which builds a bicycle visually from components the user selects. What do you think, can this be done with HTML5/JavaScript (jQuery)/CSS3? What do I need to know to start? What do you think the trickier parts will be?

http://www.hotcards.com/bikes_102/bikes.html

Comment: Yes, this can be done. But what do you know already of these subjects?

Comment: Also, FWIW, if you do redo this, set it to preload all the images, or even a "loading" until they are all loaded. When I first tried it, I was confused because it wasn't all loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can definitely be done in HTML/JS. And you don't even need HTML5 or CSS3 for that.

I think the trickiest part will be the positioning of the part images, especially with different frames.

Comment: I don't think it is *that* difficult to position the parts on different places when selecting different frames: just wrap everything in a 'master' div with the frame name and position parts with CSS like `.fastFrame .threePedals`, etc. It only means a lot of CSS rules.

Comment: Yup. But it's not only the frame that changes positions. There are some other parts that you have to factor in as well, e.g. the wheels and the stem.

I didn't say it's overly difficult, but I do think it's the trickiest part. Everything else should be rather straight forward and easy.

Comment: @Marcel: the whole thing is driven by an XML-based parts catalog, which references images for each part and also defines *exactly* how they fit together. All you'd need is some JS to take those pre-defined coordinates and plug them into the styles...